# Can I use UILocalNotifications and UNUserNotifications?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification, unusernotification

I have an iOS app that includes user 'alarms' - sent to user when the the app is not in foreground. I am using UNUserNotifications and all is working well in iOS 10 and iOS 11 testing.

I would also like to reach users who are still using iOS 8 and iOS 9.

In order to send notifications to the iOS 8 users, do I need to include alternate methods that use UILocalNotifications? Or will iOS 8 respond correctly UNUserNotificatons?

If I need to include both, I can use some if's to use the right one based on OS. It just seems odd that I must include a deprecated technique.

Answer (score 1):

`UNUserNotifications` are iOS 10 and higher, so won't work on iOS 8 and iOS 9. In that case you should check if is `UNUserNotifications` exists, or otherwise fall back to the older methods, eg:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UNUserNotificationCenter")) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    UNAuthorizationOptions options = (UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound);

    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions: options
                          completionHandler: ^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              if (granted) {
                                  NSLog(@"Granted notifications!");
                              }
                          }];
}
else {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: userNotificationTypes categories: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings: settings];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The UserNotifications framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) was added to iOS with iOS 10, so for any version before that, you'll need to use the older [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification). You are correct that `UILocalNotification` was deprecated in iOS 10 in favor of `UserNotifications.framework`, but before iOS 10, symbols from the UserNotifications framework are unavailable, so there's no other way. You can use a simple iOS version check to determine when to use either method:

```
if(@available(iOS 10, *)){
    //UserNotifications method
}
else{
    //UILocalNotification method
}
```